# JAVAFX Build Fails with Intellij on MAC

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, javafx-2

I have been trying to complete this step for 2 days and can't find a solution.

I am running IntelliJ on Mac 10.13.2

After creating a brand new project with nothing more than the "Hello World" Title screen I attempt to build artifacts.

I have my project settings correct for what I can tell and set the output to be native dmg.

the error I get is:

```
Error:Java FX Packager: 
BUILD FAILED
/Users/silverapple/Library/Caches/IdeaIC2017.3/compile-server/asi-sync_34d86456/_temp_/build.xml:29: Error: Bundler "DMG Installer" (dmg) failed to produce a bundle.
Total time: 1 minute 13 seconds

Error:Java FX Packager: Buildfile: /Users/silverapple/Library/Caches/IdeaIC2017.3/compile-server/asi-sync_34d86456/_temp_/build.xml
build artifact:
No base JDK. Package will use system JRE.
No base JDK. Package will use system JRE.
Building DMG package for JavaFXApp
Error:Java FX Packager: fx:deploy task has failed.
```

I have googled up and down and can not figure out why I can not get a build.

**The weird thing is that this process produces a mounted dmg package on the desktop that runs fine. But nothing in the build folder.**

Comment: It's a known problem: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-181533, try workaround from comments

Comment: Thank you. I just found this last night. Leaving the question for exposure as it is still not resolved. The work-around i chose was to build to an img instead of dmg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jan 17th, 2018

Posting the work around I found here as it may not be obvious to some. It wasn't to me as a Mac Noob  who thought a dmg build was the only way to go.

This is a known issue and can be tracked [here...](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-181533)

**If you specify "img"** as the native bundle in IntelliJ Project Settings you will get an .app package in the build folder.

The user can copy this to the Application folder and run it from there.

**NOTE:** For me the app was un-signed so it was blocked by GateKeeper. Command click allowed me to open it and set it to a trusted app.

Comment: I moved the .app file to the application folder and when I try to run it says the application is damaged or incomplete